# Converting Decimal Value to Hours and Minutes and also to Hours

Tags: sql-server-2008

I store time like this

1.30 == 1 Hour 30 minutes

2.70 == 3 Hours 10 minutes

I need to convert 2.70 to 3 Hours 10 minutes

And also 3 hrs 10 minutes in to Hours

How to solve this in SQL server 2008

Please help me

Comment: sql server is not a calculator..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 1.30 = 90 minutes then 1 = 69.23076923076923 minutes

Then 2.70 to minutes ->

2.70 * 69.23076923076923 = 186.9230769230769 (minutes)

186.9230769230769 / 60 (minutes in an hour) = 3.115384615384615

From 3.115384615384615 you take the integer part as hour (3) and the decimal as the minutes (1153.....)

I don't know exactly how you came up with the formula but it seems that the conversion factor is going to give you decimal places that you are going to have to take into account (round or eliminate them)

Use the same procedure but INVERSED to get from 3 hours 10 minutes to 2.70

BUT like it was mentioned before, I don't understand why you are using SQL to do this formula calculation.